# .htaccess in Apache2 for php urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to map any URL such as `localhost/first` to `localhost/first.php` using mod_rewrite for Apache on Ubuntu 15.04.

Here are the steps.

1. Installed Apache2, PHP5 using (apt-get apache2, php5)  Enabled PHP in Apache, so `phpinfo()` prints proper info.
2. a2enmod rewrite, restart apache
3. In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, added following in proper place.

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       <Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   -- Restart Apache
   ```
4. `.htaccess` in `/var/www/html`,

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
   ```
5. `chmod 644 /var/www/html/.htaccess`
6. Restart Apache

But a request like `/localhost/second` does not translate to `second.php`.

1. Edited `.htaccess`, changed last line to `RewriteRule ^second$ second.php`. Yet no sucess.
2. In Apache error.log, I see the error:

   > AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/second (None could be negotiated).

Can someone please help?

Comment: could you add `RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"`

`RewriteLogLevel 9`
to your Rewrite rule and post the content of the rewrite.log?

Comment: Thanks Broco. However, while searching some more, I discovered that removing 'Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews' magically fixed it, though I am not sure if that's the right solution.
I am too embarrassed to ask what's RewriteLogLevel, and how to set it. Will do and post the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The loglevel just means that everything concerning the Rewrite is logged, not only errors and warnings so you can see specifically what Rewrite does once you call an URL.
Basically MultiViews does exactly the same as your rewrite rule but it is considered less safe because it is a more "global" approach.
E.g. if you leave MultiViews in your Options and add a line `MultiViews Any` you will have exactly the same behaviour as with your rewrite rule except that MultiViews also checks for mimetypes etc. unless you set it to something else but "Any".

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
> ```

The `MultiViews` option is probably causing this issue. This should be removed. `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) will attempt to internally rewrite a request for `/file` (where some `/file<.ext>` exists on the filesystem) by testing the various files found in that directory and will serve the file that matches the appropriate mime-type. This happens *before* mod_rewrite has a go and can result in a conflict (since you are trying to do a similar thing with mod_rewrite).